# Angular Material Input on Chrome all input focused after pressing enter

Tags: angular, google-chrome, input, focus

I'm having a problem on Chrome with the material fields on an Angular project.

When I press the "Enter" key in a text field, all the other fields on the page go into focus.

I can't figure out where this problem come from.

On firefox the problem does not occur.

I try to prevent default or stop propagation but nothing change...

You can reproduce the problem via the following stackblitz link :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnsxg4-zvsuon?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-hint-example.html

How to reproduce :

- Position yourself on the "Input 4" field
- Press the "Enter" key
- [All fields are in focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M07Fe.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's working as expected in the stackblitz which you shared. If I type something in the first input box and if I press enter, focus stays in the first input box itself. Check updating the chrome. Also I see there are errors logged in the `handleEnterKeyPress` method you shared in stackblitz. What is the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Strange, my chrome is up to date and I have always this stange behavior.
The console.error is just for debugging and confirm that I enter in this method.
In this method I tried to block the propagation of the click event or prevent default browser behavior to avoid my strange behavior (without success).